# Find the touched Area (country)on a UIImageView based on coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

[image]

I am Using A UIImageView with a globe image,if i touch on any region Example if i touch on any African country,I would like to fire a touch event and show that it is a particular country tapped by the user.I approached the way to get he co-ordinates on the images,Please give me any suggestions how can i get the touched positions country wise.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put the Image in UIImageView of a ViewController in Portrait mode

implement

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let  touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        println(touch.locationInView(self.view))

    }
```

result

```
(155.5,164.5)
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed,I already got the co-ordinates x and y,but i need to identify the color of the area touched,Suppose the Area is red and the user touches on the border or any where in the middle of that area

Comment: Easier solution you will need to store rectangle for each country 
and  compare for them
 

        var Egypt_rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100) // Egypt
        var India_rect = CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 100) // India
        
       var exist =  CGRectContainsPoint(Egypt_rect, touch.locationInView(self.view)) ;
        if exist
        {
        
        }